# TFS server filling event log with error messages

Tags: tfs

(Had to pick between StackOverflow and ServerFault, hoping SO is a better venue)

I'm practising upgrading our TFS server from 2008 to 2013. We're moving to new hardware for the upgrade to 2012 and then applying an in-place update from 2012 to 2013. As much as possible, I'm following the guides available from the [TFS Install and Administration guides](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29035).

On the plus side, everything seems to have gone well. I've got a 2013 instance that I can work with and most things seem to be working.

However, in the event log, seemingly every 30 seconds I'm seeing the following error messages:

```
You may not call this function on a different context than the original request at:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationRequestContext.GetService[T]()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseSyncJobExtension`1.CheckSchemaLockQueue(Object source)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
```

and:

```
You may not call this function on a different context than the original request at:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationRequestContext.GetService[T]()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.LockResources..ctor(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseExecutionContext..ctor(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseSyncJobExtension`1.CheckSchemaLockQueue(Object source)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
```

and:

```
You may not call this function on a different context than the original request at:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationRequestContext.To(TeamFoundationServiceHost targetHost)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationRequestContext.To(TeamFoundationHostType hostType)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.LockResources..ctor(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseExecutionContext..ctor(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseSyncJobExtension`1.CheckSchemaLockQueue(Object source)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
```

That is, three identical messages just with 3 slightly different stack traces. Unfortunately, I can't find anyone else online who has looked for (and found) help on the phrase `You may not call this function on a different context than the original request`. (In fact, I only get one search result, which is a pastebin [post](http://pastebin.com/zmiGSLAH) - but without any context, no answers, and I can't find any links to that pastbin elsewhere)

Looking back in the event log, these errors only started after the 2012 -> 2013 upgrade, but I don't know if that means that that upgrade caused the problem or that that upgrade includes a feature that wasn't present (and thus couldn't be broken) on 2012.

So, how do I find out (better) what's going on here, and stop these error messages? I can't in all good conscience proceed with the real upgrade when things *look* like they're working but we're getting these errors.

---

Old server: TFS 2008 (SP1) atop SQL Server Standard 2005 (SP4), Single server, Windows Server 2003 Standard x86 (SP2)

New server: TFS 2013 (Update 3) atop SQL Server Standard 2012 (SP2), Single server, Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard x64 (SP1)

(When the new server was 2012, it was Update 4, nothing else different)

Comment: Do you have TFS Reporting configured on the new server? Can you check if it works? Exception is coming from the warehouse code.

Comment: Just upgraded from 2012 to 2013 and had this problem.  Alas, the answer here is not enough.  (I tried rebuilding.)  Going to have to rollback...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to rebuild the warehouse and cube. In the administration console, if you click on reporting, you should see a "rebuild" button.

Comment: Looks like your warehouse service is on the blink. If you disable the reporting option do the errors go away?#

Comment: I think that you need to raise a call with MSFT. You can do that on the forums or by burning an MSDN support request. I would need to be onsite with access to the environment to help further :(